# "com.android.systemui.demo" sendBroadcast - Not working?

Tags: android, broadcast, demo

How can I successfully activate the demo mode for the status bar in android programmatically? I already tried this approach without any success:

[Link to an example](https://newcircle.com/s/post/1745/2015/07/10/tweaking-system-ui-tuner)

```
// Enable demo mode
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.systemui.demo");
intent.putExtra("command", "enter");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Did anyone get this to work successfully? The adb commands are working without an issue.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that it's not possible for not system apps to do this programmatically. Requires the "android.permission.DUMP" permission wich is only granted to system apps. I'll search for an alternative.